# How to find parent of a UIButton element in a swipe Gesture Recognizer function to construct an Object?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, swipe

I have created a 'swipe to left' function fired by dragging a button. I need to make an abstract class so I can make it swipe to left any parent element of the button that fires the 'swipe to function'.

Right now is linked to a UIView which is parent to that element. I tried to use `sender.superview` but it won't work.

```
@IBAction func swipeRightIncome(_ sender: Any) {
    _ = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.30, curve: .easeInOut){
        self.swipeLayer.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        }.startAnimation()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast sender as it's of type `Any` , or

```
@IBAction func swipeRightIncome(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

  let parent = sender.view.superView!.superView!.superView!

  // do what you want 

}
```

Also have to declare this inside `ViewController`

```
@IBOutlet weak var profitDrag:ViewDesignShadow!
```

Comment: I am trying this. Still getting some errors from other causes.

Comment: Used it like     @IBAction func swipeLeftIncome(_ sender: UIBUtton) {

        _ = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.30, curve: .easeInOut){



            let parent = sender.superview!
       
            parent.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -50, y: 0)
            }.startAnimation()
    } and it crashes. What did I do wrong this time @Sh_Khan?

Comment: yes , this will work also , the important that it's not **Any**

Comment: comment the crash or post it , also add more detail about the problem

Comment: About the crash it underlines class AppDelegate .. with message ”Thread 1: signal SIGBART”

Comment: can you make a demo of the problem and comment the github link

Comment: I think I got what the problem is. The button is not the direct child of the UIVIEW. The Three is like this: UIView>StackView>StackView>Button, So that's why I got the signal SIGBART error, right?

Comment: I am setting up github. Sorry I am just starting up with xCode and have a wide knowledge gap...  How can I target the UIVIEW?

Comment: Also make sure sender is **_ sender: UIButton** not **_ sender: UIView** as it's supposed that you click a button

Comment: added the view in the VC **@IBOutlet weak var profitDrag:ViewDesignShadow!**

Comment: Still doesn't work. I am getting this error message in the console 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UISwipeGestureRecognizer superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10220be10'